# how to parse json in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, youtube-api

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/LadyGagaVEVO/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10&format=5`

I would like to extract the video thumbnail and video link using PHP and JavaScript from the url above but I'm not sure how to do it, here is my attempt so far:

```
$json = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/LadyGagaVEVO/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10&format=5';
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Show some sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: "i can't find the answers" Then find better tutorials.

Comment: i edited it and shown some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP

```
  $tmp = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/LadyGagaVEVO/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10&format=5/');
  $data = json_decode($tmp,true);
```

in javascript with jquery

```
  $.get("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/LadyGagaVEVO/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10&format=5/", function(response) { 
       var data = $.parseJSON(response);
  });
```

about the illegal character, depends on what counts as illegal in your case, just do some string validation as you traverse through the object for the thumbnail and video link you looking for.

Comment: i tried to print_r the $data but nothing happens

Comment: opps sorry added an extra / at the end of the url. remove that and it all should work. same with the url in the javascript part.

Answer (score 1):

PHP: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json-decode)

JavaScript is the exact same, pretty much, just with `JSON.parse()` and no special arguments past the data.

There is no better tutorial than the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using, PHP as you are doing, use json_decode(). but  use it one extra paramter

```
$data = json_decode($string, true); // the true in the last will change into associative array
```

For JavaScript, as Kolink said, use `JSON.parse()`